# Google maps API & HTML5 geolocation, map.getCenter() giving wrong value

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to write the users current location to a database but after the HTML 5 geolocation I get the wrong value for map.getCenter().  Here's the relevant code (from 2 different Google development sites).  The complete code can be found at https://aslett.net/gmaps.

```
function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
    zoom: 17,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

 // Try HTML5 geolocation.
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
     var pos = {
       lat: position.coords.latitude,
       lng: position.coords.longitude
     };

     infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
     infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
     map.setCenter(pos);
   }, function() {
     handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
   });
  var latlng = map.getCenter();
  var url = "add_marker.php?lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng() + "&type=red";
    downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
  });
 } else {
   // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
   handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
 }
```

The problem is the line (near the bottom)...

```
var latlng = map.getCenter();
```

...I was expecting it to give me the co-ordinates that were set in the HTML5 geolocation line (4 lines up)...

```
map.setCenter(pos);
```

...but it gives me the value that was set by (near the top)...

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
```

I also tried to get the position using...

```
var latlng = infoWindow.getPosition();
```

... but that didn't work (am new to this map stuff and am grabbing at straws).

Comment: Are you making the assumption that the user allows the browser to get their location?

Comment: It's just a proof-of-concept at the moment so, yes, that is an assumption right now (as I'm the only one using it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `var latlng = map.getCenter();`, which you have added to Google's example code on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation, is executed BEFORE the `getCurrentPosition()` function. So at that time this variable is set, the map's center is still where you have defined it at the top. After that, the `getCurrentPosition()` method is fired.
You should add your extra lines of code into the `getCurrentPosition()` function.

Comment: you star! that worked a treat.  The `var latlng = map.getCenter();` stuff is now straight after `map.setCenter(pos);`.  Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark my reply as the correct answer. ;)